# what is VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to access laptop's webcam from ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I did lspci and found VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111

Can i assume that the webcam is installed? I was hoping for some device name or description.

I am not getting video0 when i did:

ls /dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often, laptop webcams are controlled as USB devices, so you may attempt to search for them with `lsusb`:

From TLDP.org's [Webcam-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Webcam-HOWTO/#IDCHIP):

> 5.1. Help, I have a USB webcam and don't know exactly what model it is and/or who the manufacturer is. What do I do?
>
> Use lsusb; it can give you an idea of what other USB devices are available on your system, too:

```
$  lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0545:8080 Xirlink, Inc. IBM C-It WebCam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0840 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Express
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Back-UPS Pro 500/1000/1500
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
```

> The numbers after 'ID' are the Vendor and Product numbers, respectively. They can then be looked up in the Linux USB ID catalog. ...

Comment: Thanks but i have Ubuntu VM hosted on a server and i want to use webcam of my laptop.
Though lsusb is showing only :
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub